# Finding a non-zero vector in Col A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Definiton: The column space of an $m \times  n$ matrix $A$, written as $\operatorname{Col} A$, is the set of all linear combinations of the columns of $A$. If $A = [ a_1 \ldots a_n ]$, then $\operatorname{Col} A = \operatorname{Span}\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$.

> $$A= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & -2 & 1 \\ -2 & -5 & 7 & 3 \\ 3 & 7 & -8 & 6
>   \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Find a nonzero vector in $\operatorname{Col} A$.
>
> Solution: It is easy to find a vector in $\operatorname{Col} A$. Any column of $A$
>   will do.

I'm confused on why any column of $A$ works because $A$ in rref form is:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 9 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$$

So wouldn't only columns 1, 2, and 4 work because column 3 is linearly dependent, and thus not a part of the span?

Comment: You could also say column 2 is "linearly dependent" since it's a linear combination of columns 1 and 3. Or column 1 is "linearly dependent" since it's a linear combination of columns 2 and 3. "Linear dependence", as usually defined, is a property of a set of vectors, not of a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third column is also in the span because it can be written as $$Col 3=0.Col1+0.Col2+1.Col3+0.Col4$$ What the rref tells you is that the columns $1, 2$ and $4$ not only span $Col A$ but they are also linearly independent. Hence $Col 3$ could alternately be written as $$Col3=a.Col1+b.Col2+c.Col4$$ for some $a, b, c$.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated the column space is the set of all linear combinations of the columns of $A$. So if the matrix is not the zero matrix, you will be able to find some non zero vector in $Col A$. Colum 3 is non zero and in fact your column space is the set of all vectors in 3D because $x\times col1 + y \times col2 + z\times col3$ gives any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.